# use firebase.auth() to get a specific user's profile or use custom collections to store and retrieve profile info

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I was expecting to see some sort of functionality to get "any" user's profile information (other than "currentUser"). Something like

> firebase.auth().getUser(displayName)

or

> firebase.auth().getUser(uid)

I have found the documentation below and seems like there is no way to achieve this using firebase.auth().

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html

So I conclude that the only way to achieve this type of functionality is to store your own user/profile information in a collection and query that collection. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Any help from experienced firebase/firestore developers is appreciated.

P.s. I am using react-native.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is possible with the Admin SDK but not with the client SDKs and that's most probably on purpose, in order to limit the possibilities to get users info from the front-end, with the client SDKs.

For example, with the Node.js Admin SDK you can call the [`getUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth?authuser=0#getUser) or the [`getUserByEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth?authuser=0#getUserByEmail) methods.

If you need to get users info in your front-end, you could write a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), to which you pass the `uid` or the `email` of the desired user and which calls one of these Admin SDK methods and return to the front-end one or more properties of the [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html?authuser=0) returned by the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think I should prefer callable cloud functions instead of storing this info in my own collection and querying it using client SDK?

Comment: Another thing, I realised neither getUser nor listUsers methods accept displayName as argument. So, if I have a search box where my users can search for other users by their displayName, then these adminSDK functions won't be of any use. Storing data in my own collections and query users through that collection using clientSDK seems to be the way to go. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the way to go in this case. As you have noted, storing users info in a dedicated collection is really common! Just take care to set the correct security rules!