# How would i do this but on a specific user instead of sigend in user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I know of user.metadata.creationTime
but how do i do it on a specific user id

I hope you will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The client-side SDKs for Firebase only expose the properties of the currently signed in user. There is no way to get the creation time (or any other properties) for another user, as that'd be a security risk.

The common workaround is to either wrap the relevant functionality of the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) in a custom endpoint and call that from your app, or to have each user write the data into a cloud-accessible database (such as Firestore or Realtime Database) and then read it from there.

In both cases, consider how you want to protect access to this data though, as without that you risk exposing data of your users.

Also see:

- [Get user properties by user id Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834241/get-user-properties-by-user-id-firebase)
- [use firebase.auth() to get a specific user's profile or use custom collections to store and retrieve profile info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850952/use-firebase-auth-to-get-a-specific-users-profile-or-use-custom-collections-t)